# What is the domain of definition of the function

Tags: calculus

What is the domain of definition of the function

$f\left(x,y\right)\:=\:\frac{3x^2y}{\sqrt{x^2+2y^2}}$

Attempt:

$x^2+2y^2>0$

$x^2>-2y^2$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the numerator and denominator both have to be defined, and the denominator cannot be $0$. $3x^2y$ is defined for all $x,y$, so there's no problem there. For $\sqrt{x^2 + 2y^2}$, we need $x^2 + 2y^2 > 0$, and we know that $x=y=0$ causes the denominator to be $0$, so $f(x,y)$ is undefined at the origin. Besides that $x^2>0$ and $y^2>0$ for all $x,y$, so $\sqrt{x^2 + 2y^2} > 0$ as long as $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$. Hence, the domain of definition is $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0)\}$.